# Can't add keyValuePair directly to Dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary, key-value, generic-collections

I wanted to add a `KeyValuePair<T,U>` to a `Dictionary<T, U>` and I couldn't. I have to pass the key and the value separately, which must mean the Add method has to create a new KeyValuePair object to insert, which can't be very efficient. I can't believe there isn't an `Add(KeyValuePair<T, U>)` overload on the Add method. Can anyone suggest a possible reason for this apparent oversight?

Comment: There isn't this overload because a Dictionary doesn't only "insert" a new KeyValuePair. (I even doubt it's stored in that format under the hood) It tests if the Key already exist and probably perform some operation to place it at the right spot to keep queries as quick as possible.

Comment: You can just make an assignment: dictionary[key] = value;

Comment: what is type of your key and value?

Comment: I think you can ignore the overhead of the "Add" method.

Comment: you can alse use dictionary.Add(pair.key, pair.Value), where pair is KVP object

Comment: Seems a reasonable question to me, leaving aside the 'efficiency', it's annoying to have to add the KVP by separating it out.

Comment: Interesting because it looks like Dictionary has the same ICollection<T, V> interface with the same Add(KeyValuePair<T, V>) method but it's not showing up as an option. I'm seeing this also.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Backup a minute...before going down the road of the oversight, you should establish whether creating a new KeyValuePair is really so inefficient.

First off, the Dictionary class is not internally implemented as a set of key/value pairs, but as a bunch of arrays. That aside, let's assume it was just a set of KeyValuePairs and look at efficiency.

The first thing to notice is that [KeyValuePair](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5tbh8a42.aspx) is a structure. The real implication of that is that it has to be copied from the stack to the heap in order to be passed as a method parameter. When the KeyValuePair is added to the dictionary, it would have to be copied a second time to ensure value type semantics.

In order to pass the Key and Value as parameters, each parameter may be either a value type or a reference type. If they are value types, the performance will be very similar to the KeyValuePair route. If they are reference types, this can actually be a faster implementation since only the address needs to be passed around and very little copying has to be done. In both the best case and worst case, this option is marginally better than the KeyValuePair option due to the increased overhead of the KeyValuePair struct itself.

Comment: +1 Exactly what has been in my mind. But i've been to lazy to write it down.

Comment: "not internally implemented as a set of key/value pairs, but as a bunch of arrays": not actually true. There is *one* array of the private member struct `Dictionary<K, T>.Entry` (key, value and a couple of ints). But otherwise you're on the right track (but failed to mention *premature optimisation" :-)).

Comment: The Dictionary class uses an array of buckets and an array of entries internally to separate out the items. You're right that "a bunch" may be a bit of an overstatement, though.

Comment: Copying a `KeyValuePair<Of TKey,TValue>)` has about the same cost as copying a `TKey` and a `TValue` separately.  Constructing such a struct for the purpose of calling an `Add` method wouldn't be helpful, but if one is manually enumerating an `IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>>`, calling `Add(myEnumerator.Current);` would be more efficient than `Add(myEnumerator.Current.Key,myEnumerator.Current.Value);`  I don't see that exposing the overload would have hurt anything.

Comment: Saying "Dictionary does not internally implement KeyValuePairs internally" is at least half wrong. see https://stackoverflow.com/a/13012353/1297040
Moreover, efficiency talk is nonsense since explicit interface adds the kvp object reference with some small overhead to enforce unique key hash.

Answer (score 50):

You can use the `IDictionary<TKey,TValue>` interface which provides the `Add(KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>)` method:

```
IDictionary<int, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>();
dictionary.Add(new KeyValuePair<int,string>(0,"0"));
dictionary.Add(new KeyValuePair<int,string>(1,"1"));
```

Comment: Also note that this method does just call `Add(kvp.Key, kvp.Value)`.

Comment: @Rawling yes, it is true in the most cases, but it depends on implementation of IDictionary interface (for example the Sorted Dictionary implements it in other manner than calling Add(kvp.Key,kvp.Value))

Answer (score 18):

There is such a method – `ICollection<KeyValuePair<K, T>>.Add` but as it is *explicitly* implemented you need to cast your dictionary object to that interface to access it.

```
((ICollection<KeyValuePair<KeyType, ValueType>>)myDict).Add(myPair);
```

See

- List of **Explicit Interface Implementations** on [`Dictionary<K, T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx)'s documentation page (you'll need to scroll down).
- [Explicit member implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173157.aspx)

The [page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc673027.aspx) on this method includes an example.

Comment: You mean `((ICollection<KeyValuePair<KeyType, ValueType>>)myDict).Add(myPair);`

Comment: Thank you so much @Richard for the sane (and correct) answer! Seriously, the accepted answer goes way off track and is at least half wrong SMH.

Answer (score 3):

Should somebody really want to do this, here is an Extension

```
    public static void Add<T, U>(this IDictionary<T, U> dic, KeyValuePair<T, U> KVP)
    {
        dic.Add(KVP.Key, KVP.Value);
    }
```

*but i would recommend to not do this if there is no real need to do this*

Answer (score 2):

Unless I'm mistaken, .NET 4.5 and 4.6 adds the ability to add a KeyValuePair to a Dictionary.  (If I'm wrong, just notify me and I'll delete this answer.)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc673027%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

From the above link, the relevant piece of information is this code example:

```
public static void Main() 
{
    // Create a new dictionary of strings, with string keys, and 
    // access it through the generic ICollection interface. The 
    // generic ICollection interface views the dictionary as a 
    // collection of KeyValuePair objects with the same type 
    // arguments as the dictionary. 
    //
    ICollection<KeyValuePair<String, String>> openWith =
        new Dictionary<String, String>();

    // Add some elements to the dictionary. When elements are  
    // added through the ICollection<T> interface, the keys 
    // and values must be wrapped in KeyValuePair objects. 
    //
    openWith.Add(new KeyValuePair<String,String>("txt", "notepad.exe"));
    openWith.Add(new KeyValuePair<String,String>("bmp", "paint.exe"));
    openWith.Add(new KeyValuePair<String,String>("dib", "paint.exe"));
    openWith.Add(new KeyValuePair<String,String>("rtf", "wordpad.exe"));

    ...
}
```

As can be seen, a new object of type Dictionary is created and called `openWith`.  Then a new KVP object is created and added to `openWith` using the `.Add` method.

Comment: `openWith` is declared as an `ICollection<KeyValuePair<String, String>>`, even though it uses a `Dictionary<string, string>` under the hood. That's why that `Add()` is available.

Answer (score 1):

just because the enumerator for the Dictionary class returns a KeyValuePair, does not mean that is how it is implemented internally.

use IDictionary if you really need to pass KVP's because you've already got them in that format. otherwise use assignment or just use the Add method.

Answer (score 0):

What would be wrong with just adding it into your project as an extension?

```
namespace System.Collection.Generic
{
    public static class DictionaryExtensions
    {
        public static void AddKeyValuePair<K,V>(this IDictionary<K, V> me, KeyValuePair<K, V> other)
        {
            me.Add(other.Key, other.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I'm not 100% sure, but I think the internal implementation of a Dictionary is a Hash-table, which means key's are converted to hashes to perform quick look ups.

Have a read here if you want to know more about hashtables

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table

Comment: While correct, this has *nothing* to do with the question. So -1. (Even hash tables need to store the original values to handle collisions and also for enumeration of the keys.)

Comment: The question clearly arose from a lack of understanding the inner workings of a Dictionary. my answer enables him to answer this and further questions himself, or at least where to look for the answer.

Comment: I don't completely agree. Yes there are assumptions about the internal representation, but actually they are closer that your assumptions about the internal representation (it is a single array of structs of key, value and a couple of ints). Finally, the start of the answer deserves the -1: read the remarks on the MSDN page for the type, is states explicitly it is a hash table.