# How come Dictionary does not implement Add(KeyValuePair)

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, interface

`IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` extends from interface `ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>`, so it has an `Add(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> item)` method:

```
IDictionary<string, object> dic = new Dictionary<string, object>();
dic.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, object>("number", 42)); // Compiles fine
```

However, although `Dictionary<TKey, Tvalue>` implements `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>`, it does not have this method overload:

```
Dictionary<string, object> dic = new Dictionary<string, object>();
dic.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, object>("number", 42)); // Does not compile
```

How can this be?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13012260/cant-add-keyvaluepair-directly-to-dictionary

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you can see in [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_5) and in [the reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/dictionary.cs,195), `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` implements this part of the `ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>` interface *explicitly*.

```
void ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>.Add(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> keyValuePair) 
{
    Add(keyValuePair.Key, keyValuePair.Value);
}
```

As you have discovered, you can only call it by casting to `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` or `ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>`.

You might want to see [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/143405/c-sharp-interfaces-implicit-implementation-versus-explicit-implementation) on the difference between implicit and explicit interface implementation.

Comment: Also, because anything you find in the reference source should be taken as a "Implementation detail" which could be subject to change, you can also find it in the official documentation in the "[Explicit Interface Implementations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_5)" section to get a strong contract that this fact will not change in future versions.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain good point - will add link to docs in answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you hover over the `Add` method in Visual Studio, you will see that this method is coming from `ICollection<T>`

[image]

Now if you look at the http://referencesource.microsoft.com/  you will see that this method from interface `ICollection<T>` is [explicitly implemented](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/idictionary.cs,108).

```
#region ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> Members

void ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>.Add(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> value)
{
    //Contract.Ensures(((ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>)this).Count == Contract.OldValue(((ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>)this).Count) + 1);  // not threadsafe
}
```

That is why it is available with `IDictionary` and not with `Dictionary`